# Linux CentOS 6 load balancer and web server choose

Tags: linux, webserver, load-balancing, lamp

I'm currently testing all ways to get it done.
I will host a website project inside a Linux cloud server with dedicated resources and CentOS 6.

Now I'm stuck with apache and nginx, which should I choose? 
I read some tests, saying nginx is a lot faster.
But I have a lot more experience with apache.

Also what should I use to load balancer, Linux tools like Hearbeart, peacemaker. Or should I go with nginx upstream?

Also I looked at nginx plus LAMP where nginx serve load balancer.

Please help me to decide.

Thanks

Comment: I think the answer to your question depends a lot on what kind of application you are serving, what audience you are serving, what kind of content you might be serving alongside an application, etc. Can you provide any more details as to your goal?

Comment: well im serving an app based on Yii framework for PHP, its a gaming website, it will keep stats from various games and gametypes that user can play, so users are able to see game list, server list, other player stats, etc. 
After a match game server sends an POST to webserver API to update his stats (increase int value from many keys, like deaths, kills etc) 

i have optimized my script when possible with cache to avoid MySQL Querys

Comment: is much like that: 'cssmixes . co . uk / mixes'   but it will be wider, and support multiple games and for each game different gametypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your question and the comment you made above I'd recommend going with apache. I cannot claim to be an expert with nginx or apache, but do know that nginx is very well known for its super fast serving of static content. Apache will get the job done just fine, and being as you said you know more about apache there is nothing wrong with going that route.

As far as load balancing....it would be my opinion based off what you've said to not worry about load balancing unless you have a need for it. It might be more helpful for you to increase the size/memory/etc of your server if you are experiencing an inability to keep up with demand.

Also based off what you've said I would take a look at what problems you see in your set up and try attack those on an individual basis. Looking at the whole set up and wanting a solution will be difficult for you and anyone helping to really give you good solid advice without knowing what specifics you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Thats true, my question is also to prepare for a future, for example if using apache now, and after if i change i had to unistall, and install other and made server offline while transaction. 

so im tring to see whats better and solid to go to. Thanks

Comment: If you're worrying about load balancing now, and you want to prepare for the future, then I'd still stick to your one server now with apache. If you need to upgrade your set up later there are many ways to do so with limited to no downtime of your site.